# Google play Console show status of app is published in updated version,but user view of play store that didn't display the updated version

Tags: android

I'm a new in android development,i published app in play store,then i updated it.google play console is show the app status of published and show the correct last update date,but users can't view updated version.also show the previous version yet

Comment: i updated it in yesterday evening .not yet show updated version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update to that things :~

```
Version code is used by google play store for new update. And version 
name is displayed to the user. If you have increased version code than 
update will be visible to all user.
```

Comment: thanks Hashrit. version code and version name its correct.problem solved(i missed the rollout)

Answer (score 3):

I missed the some step(Rollout step) in upload steps.
follow the following steps.

1. Go to your Play Console
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, select Release management > App releases.
4. Next to the release you want to rollout, select Edit release.
5. Review your draft release and make any additional changes that are needed.
6. Select Review. You'll be taken to the "Review and rollout release" screen, where you can make sure there aren't any issues with your release before rolling out to users.
7. Review any warnings or errors.
8. For production releases of published apps, select rollout

Comment: Dude you just did a sneaky thing here

Answer (score 2):

You might have release an app update to production using a staged Rollout with specific percentage. With a Staged Rollout, your update reaches only a percentage of your users which you have specified, which you can increase over time.

Staged rollouts can only be used for app updates to production, not when publishing an app for the first time or creating an alpha or beta release.

For more details check this [Google Doc](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en)